# A better way to write BEM style in HTML

Tags: html, css, class, classname, bem

Lets says I am creating a component "Component" and its children or modifier. 
BEM style would be

```
<div class="Component Component--modifier">
 <div class="Component__child"></div>
</div>

I'd like write it as this way
<div class="Component Component--modifier">
 <div class="_child"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS, I would strictly write _child class inside Component scope so there isn't any globle _child class.

I wonder what potential risk or cons my style guide would cause?

Comment: I think a downside to this approach would be that you would have to rely on nesting your CSS, which could create problems related to specificity.

Comment: If the _child class is more than 3-4 levels. I can still take it out and write it as a 2nd level class in CSS. ex: Component { _child{} ). I felt there might be some inconvenience but not necessary a problem. Can you give specific example to demo your  concern?

Comment: This is probably a minor concern, but if you (or someone else) wanted to change the styles of  _child, they would have to remember to prefix their selector with Component. 

A bigger concern would be that you wouldn't be able to use _child anywhere else except under Component, which would limit its ability to be reused anywhere else.

Comment: This approach could work if you stick to class selectors and compose your classes atomically.

Comment: Isn't the idea of component is to be more specific and not letting child class being used outside component?

Comment: Components are supposed to be building blocks of an application. Ideally, a component should work on its own, and not be dependent on other components.

Comment: which means the child class should never being used outside of it's component. I think this naming style works. Thanks

Comment: It will work fine. But it isn't BEM. It's more like how CSS is designed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

An example:

```
<div class="MyRoundedBlock MyRoundedBlock--blue">
    <div class="_title"></div>
    <div class="OtherBlock">
        <div class="_title"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.MyRoundedBlock ._title {
    /* This rule applies to your OtherBlock's title too! */
}
```

Comment: yep, was trying to update the answer myself. Thanks for answer it!